# Divide most of the columns by the value of one of them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
    Name       Team    Shots    Goals    Actions Games      Minutes
1   Player 1    ABC        5       3      20       2            15
2   Player 2    ATL        6       2      15       1            30
3   Player 3    RMA        3       3      16       1            20
4   Player 4    BAR        9       0      22       3            28
5   Player 5    ATL        8       1      19       2            32
```

Actually, in my df I have around 120 columns, but this is an example to see how would be the solution. I need the same df but with the values of most of the columns divided by one. In this case I would like to have the values os 'Shots', 'Goals' and 'Actions' divided by 'Minutes' but I don't want to apply this condition to 'Games' (and some 3 or 4 other specific columns in my real case).

Do you know any code to apply what I need telling the exceptions columns I don't need to apply the division?

Comment: You can just assign them with numerical operation like `df['Shots'] = df['Shots']/df['Minutes']`

Comment: The problem is I have so many columns I can't do this one by one

Comment: Just use the list of the columns, either iterate the column names in a `for` loop or just use `div` method of dataframe and dot the bulk assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
exclude=['Games','Minutes']
#create a list of excluded columns
cols=df.columns[df.dtypes!='O']
#Filterout columns that are of type int\float
cols=cols[~cols.isin(exclude)]
#Filter out columns other than that are present in exclude list
```

Finally:

```
out=df[cols].div(df['Minutes'],axis=0)
```

### Update:

If you want complete and final df with the excludes columns and the values in this one then you can use [`join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method:

```
finaldf=out.join(df[exclude])
#If you want to join only excluded column
```

**OR**

```
cols=df.columns[df.dtypes=='O'].tolist()+exclude
finaldf=out.join(df[cols])
#If you want all the columns excluded+string ones
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a solution that can work

Comment: It works perfectly, @Anurag Dabas. How can I get the complete and final df with the excludes columns and the values in this one?

Comment: @nokvk updated answer.....Kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.div()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) to divide multiple columns by one column in place:

```
df[['Shots','Goals','Actions']].div(df.Minutes, axis=0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *in place*: that could be misleading as dataframe doesn't change when you run this code...

Comment: @MustafaAydın I mean not adding new columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is I have a df with more than 120 columns, and I wouldn't like to mention all these columns in `df[['Column 1, Column 2, etc until 120]]` My idea is a code that shows how I apply the division by Minutes to all but the ones I specifically mention.

Comment: @nokvk you can do `list(set(df.columns) - {'Minutes'})` and then pass this list as index.